# Enterprise Architect: What is the class "DataType" for?

Tags: uml, modeling, enterprise-architect

I found this on the web:

[image]

I don't understand what "DataType" is used for?

I mean, that the whole attributes from this class can be added to AD_Street class as the attribute like name, type and geometry.

When should one use this class?

What is the difference between "FeatureType" and "DataType"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

from Enterprise Architect UML Dictionary book:

"A Data Type is a specific kind of classifier, similar to a Class except that a Data Type cannot own sub Data
Types, and instances of a Data Type are identified only by their value. For example, an instance of a Person
Class is a Helen object, but an instance of an Integer Data Type is 12."

I hope this help something!